# Junit for my static method using PowerMock failing : org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

Complete error :

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException:when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'
```

This is the method I am trying to cover :

```
 public static String getCurrentTimeStamp() {
    Date date = new Date();
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
    formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
    return formatter.format(date);
}
```

Test case I am using :

```
    SearchService es = PowerMockito.mock(SearchService.class);
    PowerMockito.when(es.getCurrentTimeStamp()).thenReturn("2020-10-10 10:12:30");
```

Comment: can you show class declaration for this also i wish to know the context is it spring framework?

Answer (score 0):

First, annotate your test class with:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({SearchService.class})
```

Second, in test methods use:

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(SearchService.class);
```

Finaly, `when` invocation:

```
Mockito.when(SearchService.getCurrentTimeStamp()).thenReturn("whatever you want");
```